# GoogleFit.authorize not responding/working

Tags: google-fit

In my one of React Native app, there is a feature to connect with Google Fit. When user tapps on connects Google Fit, it prompts for device accounts to choose the account and then nothing happens, no error event receives also. I can't understand whats the issue.

Although this is working fine in debug and release build. When we upload the app to Google Play, and user downloads the app from play store, then only problem occurs.

Can anyone please help me?

```
const options = {
  scopes: [
    Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ,
    Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ,
    Scopes.FITNESS_HEART_RATE_READ,
    Scopes.FITNESS_BLOOD_PRESSURE_READ,
    Scopes.FITNESS_SLEEP_READ,
  ],
}
GoogleFit.authorize(options)
  .then(async authResult => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(authResult));

    if (authResult.success) {
      dispatch(actionCreator.getActionObject('UPDATE_isGooglefitLoggedIn', true));
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert("AUTH_ERROR", JSON.stringify(error));
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the users cannot signin using their Google account, make sure you configured the right SHA release certificate in the GCP project. When you release your App in Play Store, the signature of the binary signed by the upload key certificate will be different than the binary distributed by Google Play. You can find the Play App Signing page under Release > Setup > App Integrity and update your GCP OAuth client accordingly.